# How do I update dependencies in a Google Cloud function without deleting and redeploying?

Tags: java, scala, maven, google-cloud-functions, google-artifact-registry

If I update a SNAPSHOT dependency in my Artifact registry and then try to redeploy the Cloud Function that uses it, the SNAPSHOT is not updated. If I physically delete the function and redeploy it, the dependency is updated. Is there a way to update Maven dependencies without having to delete and redeploy? Current GCloud is

`gcloud functions deploy my-function --entry-point com.me.DoSomething --runtime java17 --trigger-http --no-allow-unauthenticated --set-secrets ...`

Answer (score 1):

For short: No.

For long, it will be never! in fact, you have to understand what happen under the hood. Google Cloud take your code, dependencies and so on, and build a container (with Buildpacks.io). Then, the container is deployed on Cloud Functions environment and served for you.

Now, and if you know the immutable nature of container, you can deduce that your requirement is impossible and will never happen.

---

About your process, you haven't to delete and redeploy your Cloud Functions, simply redeploy it. You will create a new version, with the latest version of your code and dependencies. No service disruption.

The active request will continue to live on the previous version and the new requests come to the new version

*(That's the theory. In practice, you can see glitches and you have sometime to wait 10 - 30 seconds for having your new version fully used and the oldest one abandoned).*